# xCode - Mashape API - Unirest

Tags: ios, objective-c, unirest, mashape

i need some help from you. I found a API on MaShape for Metascore but i just can't get it to work.
I used Cocoapod to download Unirest framework and copy pasted the code snippet from Mashape

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"wZrjWIiAsqdSLGIh3DQzrKoZ5Y3wlo6E"};
NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"title": @"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim", @"platform": 1, };

UNIHttpJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest post:^(UNIBodyRequest* request) {
  [request setUrl:@"https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game"];

  [request setHeaders:headers];
  [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];
```

It gave me a bunch of errors and i fixed it to be like this:

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"wZrjWIiAsqdSLGIh3DQzrKoZ5Y3wlo6E"};
    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"title": @"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim", @"platform": @"1", };

    UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest* request) {
        [request setUrl:@"https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game"];

        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJson];
```

but whenever i go and debug the code and i look inside the response it's empty as if the api didn't work. Can you guys tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (fixed) code snippet looks fine (the first one was indeed erroneous), and you should be able to print the result like this:

```
UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game"];

    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response.rawBody
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:nil];
NSLog(@"Response status: %ld\n%@", (long) response.code, json);
```

But rather than doing a synchronous call, I would also suggest you to switch to the asynchronous way, as well as checking for any error during the process and the JSON parsing:

```
[[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game"];
    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Do something with the error
    }

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response.rawBody
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    if (jsonError) {
        // Do something with the error
    }

    NSLog(@"Async response status: %ld\n%@", (long) response.code, json);

    // Unirest also provides you this which prevents you from doing the parsing
    NSLog(@"%@", response.body.JSONObject);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks dude you are a life saver. The code worked, thanks for it.